# How to select three random spots in a 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have some code that will create a 2D boolean array, select 3 of the spaces at random and assign them to true. Right now my code might select 2 of the same space and assign it to true, so it's possible that I don't end up with 3 spaces being true. How can I change my code to select 3 random and unique spaces from my array?

```
boolean mineLocations[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];

int rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
int rCol = random.nextInt(cols);
mineLocations[rRow][rCol] = true;

rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
rCol = random.nextInt(cols);
mineLocations[rRow][rCol] = true;

rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
rCol = random.nextInt(cols);
mineLocations[rRow][rCol] = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how you can do that:

```
boolean mineLocations[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];
Random random = new Random();

int counter = 0;
while (counter < 3) { //looping while 3 distinct cells are not set to true
    int rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
    int rCol = random.nextInt(cols);

    if (!mineLocations[rRow][rCol]) {
        mineLocations[rRow][rCol] = true;
        counter++; //increasing the counter only when a new cell is set to true
    }
}
```

The logic is simple: at each iteration you generate a new coordinate. Then you check if the value at this coordinate is still false (has not been changed yet). And if it is, set it to true.

Repeat it N times.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using something like:

```
//if already true, keep rolling new row and col,
//then when you find one that isn't, the loop breaks, and
//you set it to true
while(mineLocations[rRow][rCol])
{
   //try again
   rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
   rCol = random.nextInt(cols);
}
mineLocations[rRow][rCol] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a separate method for setting the initial random mine locations?

**For example:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 3, cols = 4;
    boolean mineLocations[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mineLocations));
    placeMines(3, mineLocations);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mineLocations));
  }

  private static void placeMines(int numMines, boolean mineLocations[][]) {
    int n = mineLocations.length;
    int m = mineLocations[0].length;
    if (numMines > n * m) {
      System.err.println("Can't place more mines than slots avalaible on the grid!");
      return;
    }
    int minesPlaced = 0;
    while (minesPlaced != numMines) {
      int randomRow = new Random().nextInt(n);
      int randomCol = new Random().nextInt(m);
      if (!mineLocations[randomRow][randomCol]) {
        mineLocations[randomRow][randomCol] = true;
        minesPlaced++;
      }
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
[[false, false, false, false], [false,false, false, false], [false, false, false, false]]
[[false, false, false, true], [false, true, false, false], [false, true, false, false]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first ensure that you've created three unique coordinates by randomly generating them and storing them in set, unless the size of set reaches three. And then iterate over the set and retrieve back the coordinates and initialize the array. You can code it something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Set<String> coordSet = new HashSet<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    boolean mineLocations[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];

    while(coordSet.size() < 3) {
        int rRow = random.nextInt(rows);
        int rCol = random.nextInt(cols);
        coordSet.add(String.format("%d:%d", rRow, rCol)); // set always stores unique values hence no need to check for existing data
    }
    System.out.println(coordSet);

    coordSet.stream().forEach(x -> {
        String[] pair = x.split(":");
        mineLocations[Integer.parseInt(pair[0])][Integer.parseInt(pair[1])] = true;
    });     
}
```

Few random values printed by this code in independent execution,

```
[1:0, 0:2, 2:0]
[1:0, 2:0, 2:1]
[1:0, 0:1, 1:2]
[2:0, 2:1, 2:2]
```

As you can see, none of each coordinate is the same in a single entry.

Here I've stored coordinates as a colon separated string but if you want a better implementation, you can create a custom class for storing X and Y coordinates as that would be cleaner.

As you can notice, this code will work in general for any values of rows and columns that you can initialize and the number of random points selection can also be changed just by changing the value `3` in while loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Random and IntStream/forEach

```
boolean mineLocations[][] = new boolean[rows][cols];

int count = rows * cols;
new Random().ints(3, 0, rows * cols - 1).forEach( rand -> {
  int y = rand / rows;
  int x = rand % cols;
  mineLocations[x][y] = true;
});
```